# How to simplify statement

Tags: typescript, if-statement, conditional-operator

How to simplify statement?
Admin can have unlimited count users

```
public get isUsersLimitReached(): boolean {
  return this.isAdmin ? false : usersCount >= this.max_users;
}
```

Comment: It looks fine to me. You could get a better answer if you share more code, and are more specific about what "simplify" means to you.

Comment: just set `this.max_users` to `Infinity` for admins?

Comment: This question is unclear. What do you mean with "simplify"? Why isn't the current code good enough?

Comment: This can be simplified to a `&&` or a `||`, but why and in what part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "simplify", you mean "shorten", then this is as good as it gets:

```
public get isUsersLimitReached(): boolean {
  return !this.isAdmin && usersCount >= this.max_users;
}
```

Other than that, there's really not much to work with here.

Answer (score 0):

A user limit is reached only if the user is not admin and count exceeds.

```
public get isUsersLimitReached(): boolean {
  return !this.isAdmin && usersCount >= this.max_users;
}
```